# Cannot register to GCM for push notifications on Android version 5 and 5.1

Tags: android

**GCM Notifications** works perfectly on all devices but **GCM Notifications** can not register in  **Android 5.0 or 5.1 OS**.
 I am not getting any response from GCM. Did anybody have this problem? Could you please help me?

MyCode:

```
registerReceiver(
                            OnGCMRegistrationFinish,
                            new IntentFilter(
                                    CommonUtilities.REGISTRATION_FINISH_ACTION));

                    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(
                            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                    // sets the app name in the intent
                    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent
                            .getBroadcast(Login.this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
                    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender",
                            CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);

                    Login.this.startService(registrationIntent);
```

my manifest file :

```
            <category android:name="com.xxx.xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" />

<!-- ===================================== GCM PREMISSION =========================================== -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Thanks :)